# Update Record Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am reading a book - ASP.Net 3.5 Enterprise Application Development with Visual Studio 2008 and when it talks about updating a record in the database using Linq-to-SQL it uses this code:

```
MyUserAccount ua = new MyUserAccount
{
... Update fields
};

ua.UserAccountID = Convert.ToInt32(session["UserAccountID"]);
ua.Version = Convert.ToInt32(session["Version"]);

MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
db.MyUserAccounts.Attach(ua,true);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Versus what I am used to, where I just save the AccountID in a session variable
and then get the record from the database, make my changes, and then submit the changes.

BtnUpdate

```
int UserAccountID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["UserAccountID"]);

//Get User fron Context
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
MyUserAccount ua = db.MyUserAccounts.Single(
     x => x.UserAccountID == UserAccountID);

//Make changes
ua.Blah = "";

db.SubmitChanges();
```

So my question is what is the preferred way to do this?  Having not seen this in the past I am not sure what the preferred or best way is.  Any help is appreciated.

Wade

**Note:**

My original question, someone changed my title, was what was the best Linq-to-SQL way to update the record.  So I changed the code to use session variables and the title back to it's original.  Please, read the whole question as I am only looking for the best method to update my record in the database using Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: You're confusing people with all the extraneous code.  Edit your answer to just include the two forms of linq to sql you are asking about and forget about the rest of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of sql produced the former will generate a Sql statement something like

```
Update MyUserAccount set blah=@Blah where UserAccountID = @UserAccountID
```

whereas the latter will produce

```
Select UserAccountID, Blah, ....  From MyUserAccount where UserAccountID = @UserAccountID
Update MyUserAccount set blah=@Blah where UserAccountID = @UserAccountID
```

Comment: Ok, but in the first example I needed to update all the values for the record and in my scenario I would only need to update the changed fields.  So would the first scenario not have the risk of overridding data with a null if I failed to set the field?  Thanks.

Comment: No, The Sql update statement is generated by trying to determine which columns/fields you have changed, so it will not update columns which are not mentioned or if it thinks you have not changed the value.

Comment: I should point out one thing to be aware of. With the first method, your C# code does not know what the  actual values in the database are. So if your MyUserAccount class initialises blah to the empty string, then the line ua.Blah = ""; will not be treated as a change and hence that column will not be included in the update statement. If the column in the database actually has a value that you want to remove, you may need to do something like ua.Blah = "dummyValue"; ua.Blah = null so Linq2Sql knows you have changed that column and will generate Sql like Update MyUserAccount set blah=null ...

Answer (score 1):

Do neither, store critical data like that into the session.  Hidden fields (viewstate is a hidden field) are possible to be tampered by the user.  Session will prevent the user from being able to change the value.

Comment: The question was not really about the variables, someone else changed my title.  I have changed the question to reflect my original question.

Comment: That can lead to session bloat, and can cause problems with scalability.  It shouldn't be any problem storing this information in ViewState or a hidden field so long as you have security in your app that doesn't allow access to data the user isn't supposed to.  This is a poor reason to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The example from the book is storing the useraccount and version information in [viewstate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#View_state) - which is a big hidden field that asp.net uses to maintain state and store form variables in.  In fact your hidden field will probably be in viewstate if you have viewstate turned on.

If you turn viewstate off and use your hidden field then the page will probably load faster (due to the bloat involved in maintaining viewstate).  But that may affect functionality.

Also the linq to sql statement in your code will generate a different outcome from the book - so I'd assume that the book code won't update as you would wish without being adapted to your needs.

@Matthew is right if you have security concerns then a plaintext hidden field is a bad place to store something (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Viewstate adds a bit of encryption on the data so you it cannot be easily tampered with as opposed to doing it with raw hidden field. Best approach with user info would be to store it in session.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question, I am not looking to what is the best way to save the UserAccountID, but what is the best way to update the record in the database using Linq-to-SQL.