# Update SQL record without retrieving from the database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL. 
I have an object with an ID property and I want to update it on the database. The object is outside the context.  I don't want to get the object again from the DB and then go over all the properties one by one and update them.
Can I do that?
How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Record Linq-to-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957443/update-record-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Table.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548972.aspx) Method.